# Error when using setContentAlignment and setParagraphAlignment methods of Slides Service

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, google-slides-api

I have a container-bound script in Sheets that inserts a new table in a Slides page before copying data of a given Sheets range in that Slides table.

After copying the data (cell by cell) I want to set the vertical and horizontal alignments. For that I use `setContentAlignment(TOP)` and `setParagraphAlignment(CENTER)`, but both of these return the following errors:

> ReferenceError: "TOP" is not defined. (line 295, file "Code")
>
> ReferenceError: "CENTER" is not defined. (line 296, file "Code")

The full code is as follows.

```
function test() {
  
  var rnFindings = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Findings').getRange(2,2,4,2);
  var slPrez = SlidesApp.openById('1PdGCWmgUMxBnMIXgPEVQoyxm8EMvE-ub0eejV8ISmLk');
  var slSlide = slPrez.getSlides()[0];
  Logger.log(slSlide.getLayout().getLayoutName());
  
  copyTableToSlides(rnFindings, slPrez, slSlide);
        
}

function copyTableToSlides(rnTable, slPrez, slSlide) {

  var iRow = rnTable.getNumRows();
  var iCol = rnTable.getNumColumns();
  var peTitle = slSlide.getPageElements()[0];
    var iLeft = peTitle.getLeft();
    var iTop = (peTitle.getTop() * 2) + peTitle.getHeight();
      var iWidth = slPrez.getPageWidth() - (iLeft * 2);
  var slTable = slSlide.insertTable(iRow, iCol, iLeft, iTop, iWidth, 10); // hard-coding height lets table height fit to content

  // var starTableRange = create2DArray(iRow, iCol);
  
  for (r = 1; r <= iRow; r++) {
    for (c = 1; c <= iCol; c++) {
      slTable.getCell(r-1,c-1).getText().setText(rnTable.getCell(r,c).getValue());
    }
  }

  for (r = 1; r <= iRow; r++) {
    for (c = 1; c <= iCol; c++) {
      if (c == 1) {
        slTable.getCell(r-1,c-1).setContentAlignment(TOP);
        slTable.getCell(r-1,c-1).getText().getParagraphStyle().setParagraphAlignment(CENTER);
      } else {
        slTable.getCell(r-1,c-1).setContentAlignment(TOP);
        slTable.getCell(r-1,c-1).getText().getParagraphStyle().setParagraphAlignment(LEFT)
      }
    }
  }

}
```

According to [Google's App Script Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/content-alignment.html?hl=en) these are the right ENUM values. I can't figure out what else is going wrong here.

How do I set both the vertical and horizontal alignments of each cell in a Slides table, when my code is container-bound to a Sheets file?

Thanks in advance,

Vincent

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: Thanks Tanaike! It does look like you found the solution to my problem. I'm in the process of implementing at the moment, however this became part of a bigger set of functions since, so I have not yet been able to test. As soon as I do the first test and confirm that your solution works, I'll mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### From:

```
if (c == 1) {
  slTable.getCell(r-1,c-1).setContentAlignment(TOP);
  slTable.getCell(r-1,c-1).getText().getParagraphStyle().setParagraphAlignment(CENTER);
} else {
  slTable.getCell(r-1,c-1).setContentAlignment(TOP);
  slTable.getCell(r-1,c-1).getText().getParagraphStyle().setParagraphAlignment(LEFT)
}
```

#### To:

```
if (c == 1) {
  slTable.getCell(r-1,c-1).setContentAlignment(SlidesApp.ContentAlignment.TOP);
  slTable.getCell(r-1,c-1).getText().getParagraphStyle().setParagraphAlignment(SlidesApp.ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
} else {
  slTable.getCell(r-1,c-1).setContentAlignment(SlidesApp.ContentAlignment.TOP);
  slTable.getCell(r-1,c-1).getText().getParagraphStyle().setParagraphAlignment(SlidesApp.ParagraphAlignment.START);
}
```

- Please use `SlidesApp.ContentAlignment` as enum for `setContentAlignment`.
- Please use `SlidesApp.ParagraphAlignment` as enum for `setParagraphAlignment`.

#### Note:

- There is no value of `LEFT` of `setParagraphAlignment(LEFT)`. So in your case, is that `START`? If this is not what you want, please modify it.

#### References:

- [Class SlidesApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slides-app?hl=en)
- [setContentAlignment(contentAlignment)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/table-cell.html#setcontentalignmentcontentalignment)
- [setParagraphAlignment(alignment)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/paragraph-style.html#setParagraphAlignment(ParagraphAlignment))
- [Enum ContentAlignment](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/content-alignment.html?hl=en)
- [Enum ParagraphAlignment](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/paragraph-alignment?hl=en)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Correct on both counts, this is what I was missing. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Vincent Courtemanche Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.